# How to validate custom types with Joi?

Tags: typescript, validation, testing, joi

Lets say we have this TypeScript code:

```
export class Dog {
  name = 'Fido'
  favoriteFood: Food | null = null
}

export class Food {
  name: string | null = null
}

export const DogSchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  favoriteFood: Joi.object() // How to configure this correctly?? I would prefer to use FoodSchema in this line somehow
})

export const FoodSchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
})

const fido = new Dog()
fido.favoriteFood = new Food()
const res1 = DogSchema.validate(fido) // Gives no error!! 
const res2 = FoodSchema.validate(fido.favoriteFood) // Gives expected error: "name" must be a string
```

**How can I configure Joi so when I validate fido the validation also validates fido's favorite food?**

Comment: `{ ..., favoriteFood: FoodSchema }`?

Comment: Thanks Ankh. But I do not understand where to write the code you suggest. Please advise.

Comment: Inside `DogSchema`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simpel and straightforward:

```
export const DogSchema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string(),
  favoriteFood: FoodSchema // Just put the schema here! 
})
```

Thanks Ankh!